# the impact of moving from Partner Portal to Partner Community

Tags: partner-portal, partner-communities

I have a requirement where we are moving from partner Portal to Partner Community could any let me know would there would be any impact with the changes for the existing partner portal users.

Can I have any document the specifies the impacts.

Answer (score 0):

This document outlines the impact of migrating from partner portal to Partner community and the changes for the existing portal users:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.salesforce.com%2Fhelp%2Fpdfs%2Fen%2Fsalesforce_portal_to_community_migration_cheatsheet.pdf&ei=aSbAVNTUMYuwyQSm-IGICQ&usg=AFQjCNFFKfHLOjZ50cf8nTbArFaBRNrbHA&sig2=EBiXiPH6s94zVpsGH9EqaQ